# Display dropdown field by selecting dropdown list in prestashop helper classes back-office form

Tags: php, html, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.7

I want to display or hide some of fields according to change the drop down list in my back-office form, this is nit html form, its prestashop backoffice helper classes form

for i.e  if Select Type is  "category" in first dropdown list  list then it should  display the drop down for (Select category) and should hide other two dropdown(Select product,Select offer).

```php
$this->fields_form = array(
    'legend' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('My Back offie form:'),
        'image' => _PS_ADMIN_IMG_ . 'information.png',
    ),
    'input' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => $this->l('Select Type'),
            'name' => 'slider_type',
            'id' => 'slider_type',
            'options' => array(
                'query' => $slidertypes_option,
                'id' => 'slider_type',
                'name' => 'slider_type'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => $this->l('Select Category'),
            'name' => 'id_category',
            'id' => 'id_category',
            'options' => array(
                'query' => $category_options,
                'id' => 'id_category',
                'name' => 'category_name'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => $this->l('Select Offer'),
            'name' => 'id_category',
            'id' => 'id_category',
            'options' => array(
                'query' => $offers_options,
                'id' => 'id_category',
                'name' => 'category_name'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => $this->l('Select Product'),
            'name' => 'id_product',
            'id' => 'product',

            'options' => array(
                'query' => $products,
                'id' => 'id_product',
                'name' => 'name'
            )
        ),
        //                                                            array(
        //                                                          
        'submit' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            'class' => 'button'
        ),
        'cancel' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Cancel'),
            'class' => 'button'
        )
    );
```

so drop down field should display based on first drop down selection
any idea please share.

Comment: You need to add some javascript before returning the rendered Helper, or create an admin template and put some JS inside it to manage styling of the different selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle your form using jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
adminControl();
$('#slider_type').change(function(){
    adminControl();
});
});
function adminControl(){
//main value
var type_value = $('#slider_type').val();

var handle1 = $('select#xxxx').parents().eq(2);
var handle2 = $('select#yyyy').parents().eq(2);

switch (type_value) {
    case 'category':
        handle1 .show(500);
        handle2 .hide(500);
        break;
    case 'cms':
        handle1 .hide(500);
        handle2 .show(500);
}
}
```